# Issue with pipes and fork, it only goes to the child process once instead of everytime I want

Tags: c, fork, pipe

So the code is this one:

```
int main () 
{
  int pid, fd[2], i, j;
  char comanda[1000], comm[100][100], *var, *var2, vect[100][100], text[1000], check[10000];
  if(pipe(fd)<0) 
  {
    perror("pipe error");
    exit(1);
  }
  if((pid = fork()) < 0 ) 
  {
    perror("fork error");
    exit(1);
  }
  j = 0;
  if(pid){ 
      do {
        if( j > 0) fgets (check , 1000 , stdin); //just in case there's still something in the buffer
        printf("enter command: \n");
        scanf("%[^\t\n]", comanda);
        if(var = strtok(comanda, " "))
        {
          i=0;
          while(var != NULL)
          {
            strcpy(vect[i], var);
            var = strtok(NULL, " ");
            i++;
          }
        }
        else
          strcpy(vect[0], comanda);
        if(strcmp(vect[0], "login") == 0)
        {
            write(fd[1], "login ", 6);
            write(fd[1], vect[1], strlen(vect[1]));
            printf("I got login");
        }
        else if(strcmp(vect[0], "quit") == 0)
        {
          exit(1);
        }
        else
          printf("I got the command %s \n", vect[0]);
        j++;
      } while(1);
      close(fd[0]);
      close(fd[1]);
      wait(NULL);
  }
  else
  {
      close(fd[1]); 
      printf("copil? \n");
      int i=0;
      read(fd[0], text, sizeof(text));
      var2 = strtok(text, " ");
      j=0;
      while(var2 != NULL)
      {
        strcpy(comm[j], var2);
        var2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        j++;
      }
      if( strcmp(comm[0], "login") == 0)
      {
          //comanda e login, deci verificam username-ul. 
          if(login(comm[1]))
          {
            printf("OK, Logged IN! \n");
          }
          else
          {
            printf("Username not in /etc/passwd \n");
          }
      }
      close(fd[0]);
      exit(0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What I want is to read commands from the console line and everytime I get a known command, to go to the child and execute it. Right now it reads the commands fine, the login works fine BUT only ONE time. After that, it still gets the login, it prints "I got login", but it doesn't go to the child and check it if it's ok or not.

Answer (score 2):

You have three major problems that I can see:

1. The first is that you don't terminate the string you read from the pipe in the child;
2. The other, and the source of your problem, is that the child does not loop, but performs once and then exits;
3. The third would be if you change the child to loop, and you exit the parent process then the child process would be abandoned, and just keep on waiting for input that never comes.

Comment: Thanks...But, any idea on how should I correct the code in order to work for what I need?

Comment: @FinalDestiny Point two in my answer, you should loop in the child just as you do in the parent.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your child process just exits. It seems that first "read(fd[0], text, sizeof(text));" blocks until it will receive some data from parent process. Then it executes data and exits.

BTW it is good idea to call waitpid function to avoid zombie process which could be some problem with your application. What is more you should "close(fd[0]);" at the beginning of parent process not at the and with "close(fd[1]);"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My idea was to control another process through a pipe like it would get input from the keyboard/stdin. It was the classical need of inter process communication with application that are not designed for it.

The problem was, that all the example codes just worked once at the beginning to send something to the child process stdin. It appeared to me that the pipe has to be closed on parents side so that the child side receive the data. Once closed I couldn't "reopen" it to send another command.

What saved my day was this:
http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal

I do not know why it took me almost two days to figure it out, because it sound really obvious thing to to after all. I'm posting this here, because I landed on this side and the answers wasn't really solving my problem.

Sincerely,
Robert